# RSA Cryptography returns "ILLEGAL_USE" in Java Card applet

Tags: java, javacard

I wrote the following applet to do RSA cryptography operations in my NXP JCOP card:

```
package testPack;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.CryptoException;
import javacard.security.KeyBuilder;
import javacard.security.KeyPair;
import javacard.security.RSAPrivateKey;
import javacard.security.RSAPublicKey;
import javacardx.crypto.Cipher;

public class Test extends Applet {

    RSAPrivateKey myRSAPriKey;
    RSAPublicKey myRSAPubKey;
    Cipher myCipher;
    KeyPair myKeyPair;
    byte[] input;
    byte[] result;

    private static final byte INS_GEN_KEYPAIR = (byte) 0x10;
    private static final byte INS_INIT_CIPHER_ENC = (byte) 0x20;
    private static final byte INS_ENC = 0x21;
    private static final byte INS_INIT_CIPHER_DEC = (byte) 0x30;
    private static final byte INS_DEC = (byte) 0x31;

    private static final byte P1_CHAIN_APDU = (byte) 0x00;
    private static final byte P1_LAST_APDU = (byte) 0x01;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new Test();
    }

    protected Test() {
        myRSAPriKey = (RSAPrivateKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PRIVATE, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
        myRSAPubKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
        myKeyPair = new KeyPair(myRSAPubKey, myRSAPriKey);
        myCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1, false);
        input = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 256, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
        result = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 256, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buff = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte ins = buff[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];
        byte p1 = buff[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1];
        short lc = (short) (buff[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] & 0x00FF);
        short dataOffset = ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA;

        switch (ins) {
            case INS_GEN_KEYPAIR:
                myKeyPair.genKeyPair();
                break;

            case INS_INIT_CIPHER_ENC:
                myCipher.init(myRSAPubKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
                break;
            case INS_ENC:
                apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
                if (p1 == P1_CHAIN_APDU) {
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buff, dataOffset, input, (short) 0x00, lc);
                } else if (p1 == P1_LAST_APDU) {
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buff, dataOffset, input, (short) 128, lc);
                    try {
                        myCipher.doFinal(input, (short) 0x00, (short) 256, result, (short) 0x00);
                    } catch (CryptoException e) {
                        short reason = e.getReason();
                        ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) 0x6B00 | reason));
                    }
                    apdu.setOutgoing();
                    apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) 256);
                    apdu.sendBytesLong(result, (short) 0x00, (short) 256);
                }
                break;
            case INS_INIT_CIPHER_DEC:
                myCipher.init(myRSAPriKey, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
                break;
            case INS_DEC:
                apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
                if (p1 == P1_CHAIN_APDU) {
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buff, dataOffset, input, (short) 0x00, lc);
                } else if (p1 == P1_LAST_APDU) {
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buff, dataOffset, input, (short) 128, lc);
                    try {
                        myCipher.doFinal(input, (short) 0x00, (short) 256, result, (short) 0x00);
                    } catch (CryptoException e) {
                        short reason = e.getReason();
                        ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) 0x6B00 | reason));
                    }
                    apdu.setOutgoing();
                    apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) 256);
                    apdu.sendBytesLong(result, (short) 0x00, (short) 256);
                }
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that I receive `0x0005` CryptoException reason code on `doFinal()` method:

```
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.
Send: 00 10 00 00 00
Recv: 90 00

Send: 00 20 00 00 00
Recv: 90 00

Send: 00 21 00 00 80 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00
Recv: 90 00

Send: 00 21 01 00 80 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00
Recv: 6B 05
```

Questions:

1. As you know, the reason code `0x0005` indicates *ILLEGAL_USE*. But why?
2. How can I use `update()` method on cipher object to remove the transient byte arrays from my applet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1:** As stated in the `Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1` documentation:

> This algorithm is only suitable for messages of limited length. The
>   total number of input bytes processed during encryption may not be
>   more than k-11, where k is the RSA key's modulus size in bytes.

The message you are trying to encrypt does not follow this rule since you are encrypting 256 bytes of message. Since the modulus size is 256 bytes, the maximum message you can encrypt is 245 bytes (k-11). You have to consider the additional padding bytes that will be added to the message.

**Answer 2:** You can't remove both input and output buffers since you need one to store the partial result.

```js
case INS_INIT_CIPHER_ENC:
                myCipher.init(myRSAPubKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
                cipher_result_len = (short) 0x00;
                break;
case INS_ENC:
                apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
                if (p1 == P1_CHAIN_APDU) {
                    cipher_result_len += myCipher.update(buff, dataOffset, lc, result, cipher_result_len); 
                } else if (p1 == P1_LAST_APDU) {
                    
                    try {
                        cipher_result_len += myCipher.doFinal(buff, dataOffset, lc, result, cipher_result_len);
                    } catch (CryptoException e) {
                        short reason = e.getReason();
                        ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) 0x6B00 | reason));
                    }
                    apdu.setOutgoing();
                    apdu.setOutgoingLength(cipher_result_len);
                    apdu.sendBytesLong(result, (short) 0x00, cipher_result_len);
                }
                break;
```

`cipher_result_len` is a short data that must be stored in a transient buffer.

Comment: So, which padding scheme is proper for longer data encryption?

Comment: Since your message is 256 bytes which is the size of the modulus, you can skip padding if you want (ALG_RSA_NOPAD). There is also another RSA padding ALG_RSA_PKCS1_OAEP which I'm not familiar with. Maybe you can give it a try.